# Equivalent of Hash#merge for Array? Array#merge_by_index?

Tags: arrays, ruby

What could be the name of a method which :

- Takes 2 Arrays.
- Returns 1 Array without modifying the input Arrays.
- Every element from the 1st Array is overwritten by the element with the same index from the 2nd Array.

Like this :

```
[1,2,3,4,5].some_method(['a', 'b', 'c'])
#=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
```

I couldn't find anything in the standard library. "Array merge" in other questions sometimes refers to [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip), [`Array#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-concat) or [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) but  those are not what I'm looking for.

The closest would be [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge), without block and with indices as keys :

```
{1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5}.merge({1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'}).values
#=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
```

What would be a better name than `merge` ? `merge_by_index`, `overlay`, `override`, ... ? Is there a known equivalent method in other languages ?

Is there any shorter or cleaner implementation than those ?

```
class Array

  # 1st possibility
  def merge(other_array)
    n = [size, other_array.size].max
    (0...n).map { |i| other_array[i] || self[i] } # Doesn't work when overriding with nil/false
  end

  # 2nd possibility
  def merge(other_array)
    d = size - other_array.size
    if d > 0
      other_array + self[-d, d]
    else
      other_array
    end
  end

  # 3rd possibility
  def merge(other_array)
    hash = map.with_index { |x, i| [i, x] }.to_h
    other_hash = other_array.map.with_index { |x, i| [i, x] }.to_h
    hash.merge(other_hash).values
  end
end
```

Here are some basic tests :

```
default = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array   = %w(a b c)

p default.merge(array)              == ['a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
p default.merge([false, nil, true]) == [false, nil, true, 4, 5]
p default.merge((0..9).to_a)        == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
p default.merge((2..6).to_a)        == [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
p [].merge((2..6).to_a)             == [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
p [1, 2, 3].merge([])               == [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Downvoters : I'd be happy to hear any constructive criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Array
  def merge(other_array)  
    other_array + (self[other_array.size..-1] || [])    
  end  
end
```

Comment: `undefined method '▷' for Array:Class`. :) Nice solution!

Comment: Interesting. Does it bring any advantage?

Comment: I have removed them. Yes, it brings an advantage of seeing scopes with an aesthetics :)